# Web and email host migration - Limitations and suggestions to make the process as easy as possible

Tags: hosting, migration

I developed a website for a friend of mine to replace his current 'all inclusive' provider (website creation, updating, web hosting, email hosting).

I've already paid for a hosting service which currently houses the website which I have created. I need to cancel the previous service provider to get the domain migrated to the new host, however I will still need to transfer or recreate all of the email addresses that everyone in his company had previously. Is there an easy way migrate email accounts (still linked to the same domain) while migrating to a different host? Will any methods allow all users to retain their archived emails and folder structures? What is the process to do so.

Because the current provider is a rather large website development and hosting company, I will have limited access to the data they have stored.

As you can probably tell, my knowledge in this area is very limited - any/all suggestions you may have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

-Jack

Answer (score 1):

The provider won't send the data to the new one, and they probably don't use the same solution, and so data structure anyway.

To automate user account creation, i guess you can dump/export users accounts list in csv/text and import on the new one.

For the data, the best way is to:

- Download mailbox, through imap/pop locally to the desktops
- Add the new account to outlook/mail application (while keeping the old one)
- Drag and drop the mails from the old to the new (imap/exchange mode)
- Keeps both account until the migration is over (24h for dns propagation or so)
- When the old account does not receive any more mail, remove it

yes, this way is done on the user desktop/mail application

You can automate this work through imapsync stuff, but harder

going to Google Apps ?